# How can I delete an image in my image folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I can delete an image in my database but not in an image folder.
I want to delete also the image in folder when I delete the row.

```
public IActionResult Delete(int? id,MotorModel motor)
{
    var motors = db.Motors.Find(id);
    var filename = motor.Image.FileName;
    var delete = Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Image");
    var filePath = Path.Combine(delete, filename);

    if (motors == null)
    {
        return View();
    }

    db.Entry(motors).State = EntityState.Deleted;

    if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: If you put the code in a try/catch block, what exception is raised?   Does the File.Exists call return true?

Comment: it show me this : "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in this line code : var filename = GetUniqueFileName(motor.Image.FileName);

Comment: Which line is giving you the object exception?  The error would indicate that one of your values is null.  There are a couple of locations where this could happen, i.e. id could be null, motor could be null, you should probably check for this before you use them in your code.

Comment: in this line var filename = motor.Image.FileName; i use it when i upload the file

Comment: Can you verify that `motor` and `motor.Image` are both not null?

Comment: yes both of it not null

Comment: So `motor.Image.FileName` must be null then, otherwise you would not get a null object exception..  What value do you see when you debug `motor.Image.FileName`

Comment: Path.Combine [will take more than two arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String___) by the way

Comment: @Leo0404 Your first comment says the crash occurs on line `var filename = GetUniqueFileName(motor.Image.FileName);` but the code you posted does not contain this exact line of code. Always make sure the code you post is the code you're running, otherwise you're potentially wasting everyone's time

Comment: GetUniqueFileName just simply add more character in image name and i delete it to see easier

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because you've made the questionable decision to have a method argument `MotorModel motor` and a local variable `car motors = db.Motors.Find...` and you're getting confused as to which motor/motors you're supposed to be using. Xavier is asking you "is anything null?" and you're looking in `motors` and going "nope, nothing is null" and the code is trying to delete based on `motor` instead

In my opinion a delete method need only take an id, it should look up what to delete based on that id and remove the file that is tracked by the db. It should not take an id and some other user provided data (motormodel) and delete files based on what it finds in the user provided data. It opens you up to abuse/hacking attempts if you're allowing the user to choose what files to delete arbitrarily by modifying the data provided. On that point too you should verify, given that the is to delete is an int, that the user truly owns the file they are deleting otherwise some script kid will just write a loop that calls Delete(1), Delete(2) ... Delete(10000000) and hose the entire contents of your server, for a laugh

As a style tip, a Find method will only return one entity so the variable to which it is assigned shouldn't have a plural name. Use plurals for collections of items